# Call Application Process that saves/downloads as an attachement

Tags: oracle, attachment, oracle-apex, procedure

I have a report link (inside of a classic style apex report) that calls an application process. It is set on the REQUEST attribute and is as follows:

```
APPLICATION_PROCESS=profile
```

The application process calls a procedure (Name of procedure is also "profile") inside of a package. The application process is as follows:

```
declare
begin
    util_pck.profile(:ID)
end;
```

The package generates some text inside of a webpage. Instead of generating text, upon clicking the link, I need it to prompt the user to download or save as an attachment with respect to its mime type (which I believe is .pro). I think I'm missing some key lines of code. The procedure is as follows:

```
procedure profile(profileid in number, debug in varchar2 default null) is 
cursor svyc is select p.profile_start_x, p.profile_start_y, 
p.surveying_org_full_name, p.survey_job_title, m.filename, m.vertical_accuracy_type, 
                      m.horizontal_datum, m.vertical_datum, m.epoch, m.projection_zone, m.units_of_measure, 
                      m.survey_job_number, m.survey_start_date  from survey_profiles_view p 
                      left join survey_metadata_view m on m.survey_id = p.survey_id 
                      where p.survey_profile_id = profileid;
svycitem svyc%rowtype;
cursor proc is select geom.x, geom.y, pp.* from survey_profile_pts_view pp, table(sdo_util.getvertices(pp.shape)) geom where survey_profile_id = profileid;
pro proc%rowtype;

begin
open svyc;
fetch svyc into svycitem;
owa_util.mime_header('text/plain', false);
owa_util.http_header_close;

htp.p('T01   FILE NAME  : ' || rpad(svycitem.filename, 22) || ' ORDER: ' || rpad(svycitem.vertical_accuracy_type, 10)|| ' HORIZ. DATUM: ' || svycitem.horizontal_datum || chr(13));
htp.p('T02   JOB NUMBER : ' || rpad(svycitem.survey_job_number,22)|| ' UNITS: ' || rpad(svycitem.units_of_measure, 10) || ' VERT.  DATUM: ' || svycitem.vertical_datum || chr(13));
htp.p('T03   SURVEY DATE: ' || rpad(svycitem.survey_start_date, 22) || ' ZONE : ' || rpad(svycitem.projection_zone, 10) || '        EPOCH: ' || svycitem.epoch ||chr(13));
htp.p('T04   BANK REF.  :                      CHANNEL:                                                     ' || chr(13));
htp.p('T05   CONTRACTOR : ' || svycitem.surveying_org_full_name || chr(13));
htp.p('T06   LEVEE DIST.: ' || chr(13));
htp.p('T07   TITLE      : ' || svycitem.survey_job_title || chr(13));
for pro in proc loop
  htp.p(lpad(to_char(round(pro.station, 2), '9999990.99'), 15) || lpad(to_char(round(pro.x, 2), '9999990.99'), 15) || lpad(to_char(round(pro.y, 2), '9999990.99'),15) || lpad(to_char(round(pro.elevation,2),'9990.99'),8) || ' ' || pro.point_code );
end loop;

close svyc;

end;
```

I know I need the line `wpg_docload.download_file( );` in there some where but I'm not sure where, or if the order of my code is correct. Any help on this would be great. Thanks in advance